# Ember.js: how to get my current_user info with no requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm a beginner with ember.js, and i don't know the best way to do this:

my application has devise gem, and it's a server side mvc application until you log in. Then it's ingle page. So all my ember code is declared inside the "inner" layout. In this layout, obviously, i also have my `current_user.name` method. I would like to use this information, and not doing an http request to get it.
I think that if there could be a way to put it inside my applicationController... it would be perfect!
Any ideas? Or maybe i'm trying to do the wrong thing?

thanks,

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed your current_user's json in a data-current-user attribute on the body.

```
<body data-current-user="<%= current_user.to_json %>">
```

This way you can check if they are authenticated, and get their attributes without an HTTP call.

Ryan Bats goes into detail on this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Comment: Some other variations on this include: 1) using a `meta` tag with a name like current-user and a value of the escaped json, which is semantically pleasing; and 2) using a script tag with an id that you parse the contents of, which does not require escaping and can be more pleasant to read when viewing source.